# In Html5, draw from (0.5, 0) to (0.5, 600) to get a 1-pixel thick line on canvas. The 0.5 is strange?

Tags: html, canvas

I am reading a book on Html5 and about canvas, the following code will generate 1-pixel thick lines...  It uses 0.5 as the coordinate.  If it is changed to 0 or 10, or some integer, then the lines will be gray, and 2-pixel thick.  Why is that?  That the strangest thing I have seen lately... all the programming before on Apple or Win32 API, they go by integer coordinates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</body>

<script>

var c_canvas = document.getElementById("c")
var context = c_canvas.getContext("2d")

for (x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {
  context.moveTo(x, 0)
  context.lineTo(x, 375)
}
context.strokeStyle = "#000"
context.stroke()


</script>
```

Another strange thing is, to get a 1 pixel by 1 pixel black dot, I have to draw on 0.5 for x, but use integers for y

```
for (x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {
  context.moveTo(x, 0)
  context.lineTo(x, 1)
}
```

if I use the following, then I get a gray, "longer dot"

```
for (x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {
  context.moveTo(x, 0.5)
  context.lineTo(x, 1.5)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Thanks MiKy. I also found some explanation on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_lineWidth_example

This is the relevant content:

> Obtaining crisp lines requires understanding how paths are stroked. In
>   the images below, the grid represents the canvas coordinate grid. The
>   squares between gridlines are actual on-screen pixels. In the first
>   grid image below, a rectangle from (2,1) to (5,5) is filled. The
>   entire area between them (light red) falls on pixel boundaries, so the
>   resulting filled rectangle will have crisp edges.

[image: Crisp and Blurry lines example]

> If you consider a path from (3,1) to (3,5) with a line thickness of
>   1.0, you end up with the situation in the second image. The actual area to be filled (dark blue) only extends halfway into the pixels on
>   either side of the path. An approximation of this has to be rendered,
>   which means that those pixels being only partially shaded, and results
>   in the entire area (the light blue and dark blue) being filled in with
>   a color only half as dark as the actual stroke color. This is what
>   happens with the 1.0 width line in the previous example code.
>
> To fix this, you have to be very precise in your path creation.
>   Knowing that a 1.0 width line will extend half a unit to either side
>   of the path, creating the path from (3.5,1) to (3.5,5) results in the
>   situation in the third image—the 1.0 line width ends up completely and
>   precisely filling a single pixel vertical line.

Comment: This link explain the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure it it is the same with HTML5, but it looks very similar to how the Qt library deals with painting. Essentially, the (0,0) and (1,1) coordinates define a pixel in the top left corner - its center is thus located at (0.5, 0.5).

It has to do with antialiasing - if you "draw" a black pixel at (1,1), 4 gray pixels will actually be painted gray, between (0,0) and (2,2). Read more about this in [C++ GUI programming with Qt 4](http://books.google.sk/books?id=tSCR_4LH2KsC&pg=PA180).

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, pixels cannot be divided.  When you use lineTo to draw a 1 pixel line, the line is centered on the coordinate that you specify.  If width=1 and the coordinate is an integer, then you are asking to draw 2 halves of a pixel.

Since you can't turn on half a pixel, the library rounds to the nearest divisible pixel on either side.

Answer (score 0):

I more or less fight with that when ever I start after some time again using canvas - you are workink with "mathematical" lines not lines on the screen.

As others mentioned - a line from (1,1) to (1,10) starts between pixels (0/0, 1/1) and ends between (0/10, 1/11)

so it its 1 pixel to wide and 1 pixel to high. but nicely a bit lighter ...

My solution, if you are using the canvas for drawing only "hard - integer - lines", e.g. to create a control, is to use `transform(1,0,0,1,0.5,0.5)` (or `transform(1,0,0,1,-0.5,-0.5)` depends if you want to start it with 0 or 1)

(I use transform to get sure, that there is not a (a) or (d) again making my life hard)

just shift zero on the line "between 0 and 1" (now you know my Nickname ...)

This works fine in all my cases where I am drawing (or have to draw) "pixeled"