# Canvas shows the text blurred

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am trying to draw a sharp thin rectangle using canvas control.I want the canvas background to get loaded with an image and in foreground with some text .

Though i am able to set the color and text they are somehow appearing blurred.Is there a way to fix this issue ?

And i want to apply an image as background image for each canvas rectangle i will draw.These rectangels will appear a in a div control.So wherever there is a canvas rectangle i want its background image to be filled with the image i choose.entire div will not be filled with canvas rectangles but only half of it.Is there a way whether we can have one image for all the canvas rectangles i will draw or do ineed to draw it for every rectangle ?

html:

```
<div id="divBoard" >            
        <canvas id="canvasBoard" />           
</div>
```

javascript:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvasBoard");
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
context.fillStyle = "green";   
context.fillRect(x, y, width,height);
context.font = "5px tahoma";
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillText("cell"+i, x, y + width);
```

this is the image displayed after executing my code
[image: this is the image displayed after executing my code]

Comment: I did a little cleanup of your question.  In particular, the javascript wasn't lined up, so it wasn't clear if it's all one code block.  I can tell you now the code looks a little odd with the `var` declaration in the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with fonts not rendering as sharply on a canvas. In my project I did a workaround by placing the font in a separate DIV and overlaying it on the canvas using an appropriate z-index. This approach worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `0.5` to `x` and `y`? The html5 canvas uses antialiasing so if you want "crisp" lines, you need to draw "in between" the pixels.

You will find a good explanation on how this works in [mozilla developer reference page for lineWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_lineWidth_example)

PS. also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657671/in-html5-draw-from-0-5-0-to-0-5-600-to-get-a-1-pixel-thick-line-on-canvas)

Comment: After adding 0.5 to x and y wherever they are used, i see some improvement with lines and font.But still they are not sharp.Same case with Image also.

Comment: how do i attach my code which is in text file  in comment box here?

Comment: just edit your question or post it on http://jsfiddle.net . Can you post more code? What you have now is quite clearly missing the for loop and declaration of `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`.